# ubuntu inside Windows with ubuntu on second core

Tags: dual-boot

I saw someone running an Ubuntu terminal on theri windows PC. After asking them how they did it, they mentioned doing so by giving Ubuntu an extra core and having them run side by side. How do I do that? Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide that link?

Comment: No, it was physical person.

Comment: Virtualization allows you to do that. Read https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/virtualization.html

Comment: You can do that with VM. In VirtualBox it is called the seamless mode.